# Why does the application have to declare union semun, instead of it being in sys/sem.h?

Tags: c, posix, semaphore, unions

POSIX says this in [the documentation for the `semctl` function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/semctl.html):

> type **union semun**, which the application shall explicitly declare:
>
> ```
> union semun {
>     int val;
>     struct semid_ds *buf;
>     unsigned short  *array;
> } arg;
> ```

Why did they decide that the application has to declare that union, instead of just putting it in `sys/sem.h`? [The glibc FAQ](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/FAQ#The_sys.2Fsem.h_file_lacks_the_definition_of_.60union_semun.27.) mentions that this is the case too, but is similarly unenlightening as to why:

> #### The sys/sem.h file lacks the definition of `union semun'.
>
> Nope. This union has to be provided by the user program. Former glibc versions defined this but it was an error since it does not make much sense when thinking about it. The standards describing the System V IPC functions define it this way and therefore programs must be adopted.

Comment: Since this is used for the optional parameter, which is represented as `...` in the function signature, the name of the union is irrelevant.

Comment: As is often the case: this is just how the library was written. I agree with your assessment that it is stupid to be different and not supply users with the correct struct definition.

Comment: The usual reason — historical reasons.  The system was set up in the days before headers were universally used — before the first C standard.  It puzzles me that it hasn't been fixed — like it puzzles me that the `environ` global variable isn't declared in any header.  However, the reason will undoubtedly be "backwards compatibility".  That could be overcome by a feature test to define the union.  The application could contain `#define _POSIX_UNION_SEMUN` before including `sys/sem.h` and then the header would define the type. Legacy code would not define the feature test and would still be OK.